# EntityType has no key defined-- Composite Key, Database First

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I have an asp.net MVC web application with 3 tables, PersonType, Curriculum, and CurriculumPersonType which ties the other 2 tables together with a composite key. I am trying to run a LINQ statement against that table.  When I run my code, I get an "EntityType: EntitySet 'CurriculumPersonType' has no key defined.  Define the key to this entity type." error.

I started with this in my model:

```
public class CurriculumPersonType
{
    [Key]
    public long CurriculumId { get; set; }

    [Key]
    public long PersonTypeId { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("PersonTypeId")]
    public virtual PersonType PersonType { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("CurriculumId")]
    public virtual Curriculum Curriculum { get; set; }
}
```

and have tried adding other annotations such as:

```
    [Key]
    [Column("CurriculumId",Order =1)]
    public long CurriculumId { get; set; }

    [Key]
    [Column("PersonTypeId",Order =2)]
    public long PersonTypeId { get; set; }
```

and:

```
    [Key]
    [ForeignKey("FK_CurriculumPersonType_CurriculumId")]
    public long CurriculumId { get; set; }

    [Key]
    [ForeignKey("FK_CurriculumPersonType_PersonTypeId")]
    public long PersonTypeId { get; set; }
```

None of these seem to work.  (This is Entity Framework 6.2.0)

I have looked through similar postings on stack overflow and other sites, but non seem to solve my issue.  I think I just need another set of eyes.

Here are the tables:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[CurriculumPersonType]
(
[CurriculumId] BIGINT NOT NULL,
[PersonTypeId] BIGINT NOT NULL,
primary key ([CurriculumId], [PersonTypeId]),
CONSTRAINT [FK_CurriculumPersonType_PersonTypeId] FOREIGN KEY ([PersonTypeId]) REFERENCES [dbo].[PersonType] ([Id]),
CONSTRAINT [FK_CurriculumPersonType_CurriculumId] FOREIGN KEY ([CurriculumId]) REFERENCES [dbo].[Curriculum] ([Id])
)

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[PersonType]
(
[Id] BIGINT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY, 
    [Name] VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
)

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Curriculum]
(
[Id] BIGINT IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
[Name] varchar(500) NULL,
)
```

The other 2 entity models:

```
public class Curriculum 
{
    [Key]
    public long Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class PersonType 
{
    [Key]
    public long Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

And the DBContext:

```
public class ApplicationDBContext : DbContext
{
    public ApplicationDBContext() : base("ApplicationDbContext")
    {

    }

    public DbSet<Curriculum> Curriculums { get; set; }
    public DbSet<CurriculumPersonType> CurriculumPersonTypes { get; set; }
    public DbSet<PersonType> PersonTypes { get; set; }
}
```

My application has other tables/models etc, but whenever I try to hit any of them, I get the error above.

Just playing around, I added a PK to the CurriculumPersonType table & model, and everything works fine.  Of course I don't want to do that, because that will allow duplicate values, but it seems to be hung up on the model not having a property named "Id".

New Table/Model:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[CurriculumPersonType]
(
    [Id] BIGINT NOT NULL IDENTITY(1,1), 
    [CurriculumId] BIGINT NOT NULL,
    [PersonTypeId] BIGINT NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT [FK_CurriculumPersonType_PersonTypeId] FOREIGN KEY ([PersonTypeId]) REFERENCES [dbo].[PersonType] ([Id]),
    CONSTRAINT [FK_CurriculumPersonType_CurriculumId] FOREIGN KEY ([CurriculumId]) REFERENCES [dbo].[Curriculum] ([Id]), 
    CONSTRAINT [PK_CurriculumPersonType] PRIMARY KEY ([Id])
)

public class CurriculumPersonType
{
    [Key]
    public long Id { get; set; }

    //[Key]
    //[Column(Order = 1)]
    public long CurriculumId { get; set; }

    //[Key]
    //[Column(Order = 2)]
    public long PersonTypeId { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("CurriculumId")]
    public virtual Curriculum Curriculum { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("PersonTypeId")]
    public virtual PersonType PersonType { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: You have 2 prroperties with [Key] attribute defined. That doesn't seem right.

Comment: @Thinkhoop I have used the 2 properties with [Key] in the past, as recently as EF 6.1.3, it just seems to not work in 6.2, and there must be something I am missing that has changed.

Comment: use [Key, Column(Order = 0)] and [Key, Column(Order = 1)] instead.

Comment: @DevilSuichiro still get the same error

Comment: can you create the key via fluent api?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error "EntityType '{x}' has no key defined. Define the key for this EntityType." indicates that the DBSet is pointing at a class other than your above Entity definition. In the DbContext, using the in `DbSet<CurriculumPersonType>` right click on CurriculumPersonType and "Go to Definition". My hunch is that you have another class called CurriculumPersonType defined that is being referenced by the DbContext (such as an auto-generated class).  If the classes are in different assemblies, make sure all assemblies are built & up to date, though referenced assemblies should automatically be rebuilt when changed.

When you have an entity with a composite key using just `[Key]` without the column order the exception message is:

"Unable to determine composite primary key ordering for type '{x}'. Use the ColumnAttribute (see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=386388) or the HasKey method (see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=386387) to specify an order for composite primary keys."

Column order can be assigned by using `[Key, Column(Order=0)]` No need to specify the column name in the attribute if the property name matches. Using orders of 0,1 or 1,2 are fine, it's just used to order the columns in the key.

Comment: Your second link directed me to the problem... I needed to add the following code to OnModelCreating:  modelBuilder.Entity<CurriculumPersonType>().HasKey(t => new { t.CurriculumId, t.PersonTypeId });